# jQuery Select a page redirect

Tags: jquery, redirect, jquery-selectors

I was just wondering, is there a way of detecting a page redirect even if a user just enters the URL into the search bar? I understand that there are selectors such as `a[href^="https://some-website.com"` however, i'm looking for something a little more generic than that. All suggestions appreciated.

**Update:**

To be more specific, my goal here is to detect if a specific URL is being visited. Then, if that user is not logged in then redirect them to a log-in URL instead. I already have the jQuery in place to check if a user is not logged in and the page redirect, I am just missing the URL redirect detection.

Comment: You can use the `onbeforeunload` event to know when the page is about to be unloaded due to a redirect, but there's no way to know if this was caused by a user clicking a link to your own site, or to another site, or typing a URL in the nav bar, or just closing the tab completely.

Comment: So, by using the `onbeforeunload` event is there any way from there to detect a specific URL being loaded or is this event limited to everything that happens before the current page unloads? If I can detect a redirect to a specific URL this will solve my problem. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: `is this event limited to everything that happens before the current page unloads?` I'm afraid so. You only know that the current page is being unloaded. There is no reliable way to detect from this event where the new URL will be - or even if there is one

Comment: Ahh I see. Well I will have to stick with catching the events via anchor tags for now. Hopefully there will be ways to do this eventually. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

`window.location.replace(...)` is better than using window.location.href, because `replace()` does not keep the originating page in the session history, meaning the user won't get stuck in a never-ending back-button fiasco.

```
<form>
   <input type="text" class="url">
   <input type="submit" class="submit">
</form>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $('.submit').on('click',function(){
             // similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
             window.location.replace($('.url').val());

             // similar behavior as clicking on a link
             window.location.href = $('.url').val();
         });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: My goal here isn't to create a page redirect, I am trying to figure out if there is a way of checking if a page is already being redirected to so I can execute some code before the user reaches that URL. Apologies if I was vague within my question

Comment: Did you save the record of user redirected of which url . You can do it if you have the list of record

Comment: Unfortunately not, however I need to be able to detect a URL redirect even if a user hasn't visited that URL of the website before. For more specifics on what i'm trying to achieve I have updated the question

Comment: @A.Fletcher Just save the record by ajax , After logged in a user on which url he visited you can detect them with list of record either no way to track them

Answer (score 0):

So, this is definitely not the most graceful way of going about this and I don't want to accept this as the answer in the hope something better comes around. But, by using:

```
let path = window.location.pathname;

if(path == "/YourPathHere"){
    //Some code here
}
```

This will execute whenever a user gets to that page. The main problem in my case is that when i'm redirecting to a login page afterwards this causes 2 redirects and potentially confusing users on the website.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look into cookies. If your user logged in you set a cookie, for example "Login" = True

Then you check your cookie on every site where you have to be logged in, if your cookie "Login" != true window.location='url'